# How can I load a .swf with an embedded xml file, and then instantiate an object from that xml file?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

Basically, I'm working on a flash game, and I want to be able to load mods into the game. Each mod would be a .swf file with an embedded xml file that holds all the information about the mod (name, version, main class, etc.) and then instantiate that main class (which extends a class Plugin). I have a mock-up of basically how I want to do it (from my experience in Java), but I'm not too clear on things such as embedding, can someone guide me?

Rough example:

```
//Loads the .swf file
private var i:int = 0;
private static function onLoadComplete(e:Event) {
    //xml would (supposedly, not too sure how this works) be the embedded xml file
    var pluginMain:Class = getDefinitionByName(e.target.content.xml.Main[0]) as Class;
    var plugin = new pluginMain();
    //initiate() is a function of my class Plugin, which plugin should extend
    plugin.initiate(this);
    plugins[i] = plugin;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed an XML file in a SWF by using the `Embed` tag with correct MIME type. The class variable defined directly beneath will contain the embedded file's data when instantiated. Here's a sample document class that embeds an XML file, instantiates it when loaded, and dispatches a 'READY' event once it has done so:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Mod extends Sprite {

        [Embed(source="../xmldir/mod_data.xml", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
        public var ModData:Class;

        public static const READY:String = "READY";

        public var modXml:XML;
        public var ready:Boolean = false;

        public function Mod() {
            data_init();
        }

        private function data_init():void {
            var modDataXML:XML = XML(new ModData());
            ready = true;
            dispatchEvent(new Event(READY));
            //trace(modDataXML.Main[0]);
        }

    }
}
```

You can listen for the event from your `Loader`'s `content` property, or just check the `content.ready` property, in case it's already fired.